# Quickly interpolate missing values in R plot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I would like an efficient way to plot data frames with missing values as a line plot in R, by the following rationale;

- NAs in first and last values are omitted completely (no line/dots)
- NAs within actual values are replaced with intermediate values for line plotting (no dots appearing)

This is an example of my data frame (**edited**)

```
df <- data.frame("time" = c(1,2,3,4,5),
             "case1" = c(NA,2,3,4,NA),
             "case2" = c(5,4,3,2,NA),
             "case3" = c(4,NA,NA,NA,2))
```

And this is how it's working for the first case only

```
library(pracma)
df$case1.i <- with(df, interp1(time, case1, time, 'linear'))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(time)) + geom_point(aes(case1 = case1)) + geom_line(aes(case1 = case1.i))
```

I'm trying to work out something to make it work for the approximately 200 columns that I have in my actual data frame. So far this code doesn't seem to be working

```
for (i in colnames(df)){
  argument <- paste("df$case",i,".i <- with(df, interp1(time, case",i,", time, 'linear'))")
  eval(parse(text=argument))
}
```

Comment: Do you want these plotted all in one figure or a separate figure for each case?

Comment: I would like to plot them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the data into a new zoo object `z`, apply `na.approx` to it to fill in the `NA` values within the body of the data and then plot using ggplot2. If separate panels are wanted omit `facet = NULL`.  Note that `fortify.zoo` with `melt = TRUE` converts the data to long form with `Index`, `Series` and `Value` columns and that is used in `geom_point`.  Omit the `geom_point(...)` part if you just want lines. See image at end of this answer.  The approach shown here is relatively compact and avoids pasting together and then evaluating code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(df)
autoplot(na.approx(z), facet = NULL) + 
  geom_point(aes(Index, Value, group = Series), fortify(z, melt = TRUE))
```

or if you want a separate plot for each column try this instead:

```
pdf("civy.pdf")

for(i in 1:ncol(z)) {
  p <- autoplot(na.approx(z[, i])) + 
    ylab(names(z)[i]) +
    geom_point(aes(Index, Value), fortify(z[, i], melt = TRUE))
  plot(p)
}

dev.off()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That's perfect. Do you know how can I also plot the dots of the non-NA points? So that someone can distinguish where there are true values and not missing ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions: one where all data are plotted together, differentiated by colour; another where they are plotted separately by case in different facets. The principle is much the same: I use `approx` to perform linear interpolation, reformat the data from wide to long for ease of plotting in `ggplot2`, then plot it. In the second solution, I also create a new variable called `type` to differentiate between interpolated and raw data.

### Plotted together

```
# Create data frame
df <- data.frame("time" = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 "case1" = c(NA,2,3,4,NA),
                 "case2" = c(1,2,3,4,NA),
                 "case3" = c(1,NA,NA,NA,5)) 

# Perform interpolation on all columns
# Switch from wide to long format
df %<>% 
  mutate_at(vars(contains("case")), funs(interp = approx(time, ., xout = time)$y)) %>% 
  gather(var, val, -time)

# Plot results all in one figure
g <- ggplot() 
g <- g + geom_point(data = df %>% filter(!grepl("interp", var)), aes(x = time, y = val, colour = var))
g <- g + geom_line(data = df %>% filter(grepl("interp", var)), aes(x = time, y = val, colour = var))
print(g)
```

### Plotted separately

```
# Create data frame
df <- data.frame("time" = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 "case1" = c(NA,2,3,4,NA),
                 "case2" = c(1,2,3,4,NA),
                 "case3" = c(1,NA,NA,NA,5)) 

# Perform interpolation on all columns
# Switch from wide to long format
# Create column to indicate whether raw or interpolated
# Strip "_interp" from var
df %<>% 
  mutate_at(vars(contains("case")), funs(interp = approx(time, ., xout = time)$y)) %>% 
  gather(var, val, -time) %>% 
  mutate(type = ifelse(grepl("interp", var), "interp", "raw"),
         var = gsub("_.*", "", var))

# Plot results all separate figures
g <- ggplot() 
g <- g + geom_point(data = df %>% filter(type == "raw"), aes(x = time, y = val))
g <- g + geom_line(data = df %>% filter(type == "interp"), aes(x = time, y = val))
g <- g + facet_grid(var ~.)
print(g)
```

[image]

---

## Edit with new data frame

```
df <- data.frame("time" = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 "case1" = c(NA,2,3,4,NA),
                 "case2" = c(5,4,3,2,NA),
                 "case3" = c(4,NA,NA,NA,2))

df %<>% 
  mutate_at(vars(contains("case")), funs(interp = approx(time, ., xout = time)$y)) %>% 
  gather(var, val, -time) %>% 
  mutate(type = ifelse(grepl("interp", var), "interp", "raw"),
         var = gsub("_.*", "", var))

g <- ggplot() 
g <- g + geom_point(data = df %>% filter(type == "raw"), aes(x = time, y = val, colour = var))
g <- g + geom_line(data = df %>% filter(type == "interp"), aes(x = time, y = val, colour = var))
print(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer please take some time to edit it according to my new sample df. I haven't noticed that values overlap when plotted together.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right path though you have some errors in pasting up the argument you want to evaluate, on the top of my head are those:

- you should use `paste0()` to remove spaces
- you are looping over the column names but using `i` as a number
- And I would loop over columns that I want to interpolate only not all columns

Here's your code with the changes I mentioned above:

```
cols_to_interpolate <- setdiff(colnames(df), 'time')

for (col in cols_to_interpolate){
  #print(col)
  argument <- paste0("df$", col,"_i <- with(df, interp1(time, ", col,", time , 'linear'))")
  #print(argument)
  eval(parse(text=argument))
}

p <- ggplot (df, aes(x = time))
for (col in cols_to_interpolate){
    p <- p + 
      geom_point(aes_string(y = col, color = shQuote(col)),  na.rm = TRUE) + 
      geom_line(aes_string(y = paste0(col,"_i"), color = shQuote(col)), na.rm = TRUE)
  }
p + ylab('Y Label') + xlab('X Label')
```

[image]

Note: I chose this method since it was the closest to what you were trying to do, however I'm sure there is lot more efficient ways to get the end result. (Less for loops would be of-course a plus)

Comment: That works great, but only case 3 is plotted. Mind reviewing it ?

Comment: Sure! there you go, hope this helps